# CSS style not applying to text box

Tags: css, styling

I have some css that is not being applied to atext area:

```
/* Style The Text Input Boxes */
.input_style [type=text, type=date] {
background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ffa853;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ffa853;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 165px;
    outline: none;
}

/* Input Box hover styling */
.input_style:hover {
    border: 2px solid #00008B;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
}
```

and here is where I use it:

```
First Name:<input type="text" name="ud_first" value="<?php echo $first; ?>" maxlength="12" size="12" class="input_style"/>
Last Name:<input type="text" name="ud_last" value="<?php echo $last; ?>" maxlength="36" size="12" class="input_style" />
Equpment Borrowed:<input type="text" name="ud_Equipment_Borrowed" value="<?php echo $eqpmnt_brwd; ?>" maxlength="60" size="14" class="input_style" /><br />
Service Tag:<input type="text" name="ud_Service_Tag" value="<?php echo $svc_tag; ?>" maxlength="6" size="6" class="input_style" /><br />
Date Taken:<input type="date" name="ud_Date_Taken" value="<?php echo $date_brwd; ?>" class="input_style" /><br />
Returned:<input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="Yes" <?php if($rtrnd == 'Yes') echo 'checked'; ?> class="input_style" /> Yes<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
<input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="No" <?php if($rtrnd == 'No') echo 'checked'; ?> class="input_style" /> No<br /><br />
Additional Comments:<br>
<textarea name="ud_Comments" maxlength="150" cols="40" rows="3" wrap=HARD class="input_style"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea> <br /> <br />
```

I've looked at several examples and seem to be following them exactly but the styling is not being applied to the text boxes. Does anyone see what might be wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible the [type=text,type=date] is failing to match because the input type cannot be both text AND date?  I've never seen that comma-delimited format used inside an attribute predicate.

Comment: Not only that, but the space between `.input_style` and `[type=...` is the descendant combinator, but the input we're trying to select is the `.input_style` element itself, not a descendent.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, was going to ask about the space as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
/* Style The Text Input Boxes */
.input_style[type=text],
.input_style[type=date] {
background: white;
    border: 1px solid #ffa853;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 3px #ffa853;
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 165px;
    outline: none;
}

/* Input Box hover styling */
.input_style:hover {
    border: 2px solid #00008B;
    background-color: GhostWhite;
}
```

Comment: You just need to remove the gap between .input_style and the square brackets. I.e. `.input_style[type=text]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
.input_style[type=text],
.input_style[type=date] {
    ...
}
```